# How to get the sum of items in seletedIndexes in PyQt QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

Am trying to use QTableWidget in a kind of similar way to ms excel. I would like to get the sum of all items in the currentRow and show it on the same row of obviously a different column.
Here is my code

```
item = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()
table = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
table.setText(sum(item))
self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 5, table)
```

I get this error:

```
    table.setText(sum(data))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'QModelIndex'
```

Comment: please place an appropriate code, the following code is missing a parenthesis: `table.setText(sum(item)` :P

Comment: i have added the forgotten parenthesis

Comment: and when do you want the sum to be made, when a button or some key is pressed?

Comment: am using the first line of the code with item variable ie: item = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes(). i can also use a button if it's what can solve my problem

Comment: when the items are selected, i have a right-click option that uses the code provided above. the righticlick option of summation work but the code show the error as informed earlier in the question

Comment: please show that complete code.

Comment: the code is very long as works as intended. The only problem lays in the code shown above

Comment: Try with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectedIndexes returns the QModelIndex associated with the items selections, and these elements can not be added since they are elements that indicate the position of the item, an appropriate method is to use selectedItems () that returns the selected items, but neither those items must be added, what you should do is get the text and convert it to float and just add those values:

```
val = sum([float(item.text()) for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems()])
table = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
table.setText(str(val))
row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 5, table)
```

**Note:** I have assumed that the values contained in the cells represent numbers.